# Convert Hexadecimal Character from URL in php

Tags: php, url, utf-8, hex

I want to convert the hexadecimal character from URLs (e.g. %C3%A4) to the "normal" UTF8 character (e.g. ä) (like "Hexadecimal Codes to Characters" in [Hexadecimal Character Codes in URL](http://code.cside.com/3rdpage/us/url/converter.html)).
How do this in PHP?

I tested the following:

```
echo hexdec("%C3%A4"); // 50084
echo bin2hex("%C3%A4"); // 254333254134
echo dechex("%C3%A4"); // 0
echo pack('H*', "%C3%A4")"; //Warning: pack(): Type H: illegal hex digit % in ... Warning: pack(): Type H: illegal hex digit % in ... 51 0�
```

(I've to convert a word like "w%C3%A4re" to "wäre")

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
urldecode('%C3%A4');
```